# How do I spawn a daemon in uClinux using vfork?

Tags: c, linux, fork, uclinux

This would be easy with fork(), but I've got no MMU. I've heard that vfork() blocks the parent process until the child exits or executes exec(). How would I accomplish something like this?:

```
pid_t pid = vfork();

if (pid == -1) {
    // fail
    exit(-1);
}

if (pid == 0) {
    // child
    while(1) {
        // Do my daemon stuff
    }

    // Let's pretend it exits sometime
    exit();
} 

// Continue execution in parent without blocking.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no way to do this exactly as you have it here.  `exec` or `_exit` have to get called for the parent to continue execution.  Either put the daemon code into another executable and `exec` it, or use the child to spawn the original task.  The second approach is the sneaky way, and is described here.

Comment: A twist is to use a multi-call binary, then you don't need put to the binary code into another executable proper.

Comment: I believe the URL should be http://www.ucdot.org/article.pl?sid=03/12/12/0317219&mode=thread

Answer (score 3):

[daemon() function for uClinux systems without MMU and fork(), by Jamie Lokier, in patch format](http://mailman.uclinux.org/pipermail/uclinux-dev/2009-April/000684.html)

You can't do daemon() with vfork(). To create something similar to a daemon on !MMU using vfork(), the parent process doesn't die (so there are extra processes), and you should call your daemon on the background (i.e. by appending & to the command line on the shell).

On the other hand, Linux provides clone(). Armed with that, knowledge and care, it's possible to implement daemon() for !MMU. Jamie Lokier has a function to do just that on ARM and i386, get it from [here](http://mailman.uclinux.org/pipermail/uclinux-dev/2009-April/000684.html).

**Edit:** made the link to Jamie Lokier's daemon() for !MMU Linux more prominent.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought that this would be the type of problem that many others had run into before, but I've had a hard time finding anyone talking about the "kill the parent" problems.

I initially thought that you should be able to do this with a (not quite so, but sort of) simple call to `clone`, like this:

```
pid_t new_vfork(void) {
    return clone(child_func,        /* child function */
                 child_stack,          /* child stack    */
                 SIGCHLD | CLONE_VM,   /* flags */
                 NULL,                 /* argument to child */
                 NULL,                 /* pid of the child */
                 NULL,                 /* thread local storage for child */
                 NULL);                /* thread id of child in child's mem */
}
```

Except that determining the child_stack and the child_func to work the way that it does with vfork is pretty difficult since child_func would need to be the return address from the clone call and the child_stack would need to be the top of the stack at the point that the actual system call (sys_clone) is made.

You could probably try to call `sys_clone` directly with

```
pid_t new_vfork(void) {
    return sys_clone( SIGCHLD | CLONE_VM, NULL);
}
```

Which I think might get what you want.  Passing NULL as the second argument, which is the child_stack pointer, causes the kernel to do the same thing as it does in vfork and fork, which is to use the same stack as the parent.

I've never used `sys_clone` directly and haven't tested this, but I think it should work.  I believe that:

```
  sys_clone( SIGCHLD | CLONE_VM | CLONE_VFORK, NULL);
```

is equivalent to `vfork`.

If this doesn't work (and you can't figure out how to do something similar) then you may be able to use the regular clone call along with `setjump` and `longjmp` calls to emulate it, or you may be able to get around the need for the "return's twice" semantics of `fork` and `vfork`.

Comment: I wonder if that would suffer from the problem described here: http://www.mail-archive.com/uclinux-dev@uclinux.org/msg01290.html

Comment: Probably would.  Plus I haven't been able to locate a `sys_clone` library function.  It sure would be nice to have, though.